# Windows Disk Management

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, partitioning, disk-space

I dual-booted Linux mint a while ago and saved almost 50GB for it. I was successful somehow. But now I want to delete it but I cannot find any way. So basically this 50GB of space is not usable, I cannot do anything with it, and when I right-click on it, nothing pop-ups Any help?

Here look in the pic what I am talking about.

[image: Screenshot of Disk Management]

Comment: You want to get rid of Linux on your PC, that's right? If so, and depending where the bootloader is, it's best if you boot from a USB Windows Install medium, choose Install, then Custom, navigate until the installer asks where you would like to install your new Windows, and there, you should be able to see and delete that 50GB partition. Then you close the installer, confirm you want to quit install, and you should be back to the menu. There, choose Repair, Advanced, then Command line, and type "bootrec /fixboot", bootrec /fixmbr" and "bootrec /rebuildbcd", then restart.

Comment: so this wont effect my other partitions?

Comment: No, as long as you're careful, as @JoshT recommended. Once in the installer, your Linux partition should show with anything but an NTFS file system anyway, so it'll be easy to determine which is which. Just delete that partition, confirm your choice for deletion, exit the installer, go to Command line and enter the commands I mentioned, then reboot your PC.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth a shot, but go into CMD or Powershell in admin mode (just to be safe), type in DISKPART.

Once that boots up, type in 'list disk', then 'select disk x', x is the number of the disk that has the partition you want to delete, then type 'list partition', then 'select partition x', and then type 'delete partition override'.

See if that works.  Don't go off disk manager for what disk or partition you want as it may not be the same in DISKPART.

Make sure you are selecting the correct disk and partition as you don't want to delete the wrong thing.  Best way is to compare the partition size and make sure they match before selecting.

Comment: i did what you said, following was the response of cmd
Virtual Disk Service error:
The operation is not supported by the object.
The specified command or parameters are not supported on this system.

Comment: These instructions don't work because the Linux partition is on a dynamic disk, which does not have partitions but uses "Volumes" instead. Replace `partition` by `volume` in the above instructions and it should work.

Comment: Not showing that partition if find by volume